# Nginx Several projects in different directories

Tags: nginx

first of all apologies for my English, since it is not very good. I am a novice in nginx and I have a fundamental doubt:

What is the easiest way to serve several projects with nginx (separated in different directories), using a single machine, with the same ip and same port?

```
example.com/project1
example.com/project2
example.com/project3
```

A cordial greeting.

Answer (score 0):

You will want several location directives inside a single server block to do what you need to do for each project. What goes inside of the location directives really depends on the type of projects they are. I have some WordPress instances, for example, that would have fastcgi config lines inside of those location directives.

**Example:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /project1 {
        # What goes here depends on what type of project this is.
    }
    location /project2 {
        # What goes here depends on what type of project this is.
    }
    location /project3 {
        # What goes here depends on what type of project this is.
    }
}
```